# How to double the size of a matrix and propagate its elements in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, size, vectorization

suppose I have a matrix like this:

```
a = 
    1    2
    3    4
```

I want to double the size of matrix and create something like this:

```
aa = 
     1    1    2    2
     1    1    2    2
     3    3    4    4
     3    3    4    4
```

in this way, each element in the first matrix propagates to four elements in the bigger matrix.

```
a(i,j) == aa(2*i-1, 2*j-1)
       == aa(2*i  , 2*j-1)
       == aa(2*i-1, 2*j)
       == aa(2*i  , 2*j)
```

is there any predefined functions to do that?

definitely I can do that by two loops, but I want the easiest and cleanest way!

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/answers/36144-how-to-stretch-matrix

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use [`kron`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) -  Kronecker tensor product:

```
kron(a,ones(2))


ans =
 1     1     2     2
 1     1     2     2
 3     3     4     4
 3     3     4     4
```

Comment: Thanks, And I also found another way. by using `resizem(a, 2)`.

Comment: cool, wasn't aware of that function. I see the Mapping toolbox is needed though. I bet `kron` is faster :)